# Error received saying “Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.”

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, type-conversion

When setting codes using the INSERT INTO sql command the following error occurs.

> "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
> string."

Values of date & time are read from a datetime picker in form.
How can I Fix this issue?

```
{
    String conString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-2V4K24T\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Student_Enrollment_System_DB;Integrated Security=True";
    string query = "INSERT INTO Students(Registration_Number,Student_Name,Date_of_Birth,Gender,Contact_Number,Course_enrolled_in) " +
        "VALUES('" + RegNo.Text + "','" + StuName.Text + "','" + this.DateOfBirth.Text + "','" + textBox1.Text + "','" + ContactNo.Text + "','" + CsesEnrolledIn.Items + "')";
    SqlConnection conn;
    conn = new SqlConnection(conString);
    SqlCommand runquery = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

    conn.Open();
    runquery.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Student have been added!");
 }
```

Comment: Print your ```query``` and check what is it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119133/conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-from-character-string-while-i

Comment: You will fix your problems just writing a parameterized query instead of building an sql command from pieces of constant strings and values taken from your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I have a few things to say;

- It is *not* a good idea to write your connection string to your code. Usually it would be better to write it in your configuration file. See: [Where Should I Store a database Connection String?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4177060/447156)
- Looks like you try to insert string value to your datetime typed column. Don't do that. Use right data types for your data. Please read Bad Habits to Kick : [Choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)
- You are directly showing "Student have been added!" message no matter what. There is a chance that your insert command wouldn't inserted successfully. Since [ExecuteNonQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery) returns "the number of rows affected" of your query, it would be better to check it's result is bigger than 0 or not.
- Do not create your sql command using string concatenation. This makes your code is open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should always use [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) (aka parameterid queries). Jeff Atwood has a cool blog article called [Give me parameterized SQL, or give me death](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). Please read it *carefully*. SQL Injection is a very important subject when you are working with sql queries in your code.
- You open your connection but you never closed it. That's usually a bad idea. Instead of that, you can use [`using` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) for your connection and command to *automatically* dispose them.

---

```
using(var conString = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(var query = cnn.CreateCommand())
{
     query.CommandText = @"Create your prepared statement command";
     // Add your parameters and their values with Parameters.Add method
     conString.Open();
     var affectedRows = query.ExecuteNonQuery();
     if(affectedRows > 0)
     {
        MessageBox.Show("Student have been added!");
     }
} --> Both connection and command will be disposed here
```