# string was not recognized as a valid datetime using ParseExact

Tags: c#, datetime, datepicker, datetime-format

I'm trying to get data from angular and save it in database through WebAPI using C#. Now I have a problem will converting DOB , I get this error

> "string was not recognized as a valid datetime"

Angular date Format : "Wed Jan 05 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

Database date format : "YYYY-MM-DD"

Now need to convert into this format.

```
string dob = httprequest.Form.Get("dob");

MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection();
myConnection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=localhost; Database=pramod; User ID=itesuser; password=ites; Port=3309";
            
MySqlCommand sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand();
sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
sqlCmd.CommandText = "Insert Into emp_ang (DOB) Values (@dob)";
sqlCmd.Connection = myConnection;

DateTime birth = DateTime.ParseExact(dob, "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", birth);
myConnection.Open();
int rowInserted = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
myConnection.Close();
return Ok("inserted");
```

Comment: could you share one value sample of `date` you get?

Comment: "Wed Jan 05 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" value i get from client side need to change as "2022-01-05" on server side @osmanRahimi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'm so glad to see you **don't** try to save your `DateTime` as a `string` in your database. Don't ever trapped yourself with [choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type). MySQL have [`DATE` and `DATETIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html) types, choose which one fits for your needs.

Let's look at your string: "Wed Jan 05 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

There is no built-in way to parse time zone names in .NET. So, it will be better to delete that time zone name - (India Standard Time) part - in your string.

Let's say we have: ""Wed Jan 05 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0530"

Still we have "GMT" and still there is *no* way to parse it without manipulating your string or put it that as a custom part in your format. And you can parse your UTC offset part with [`zzz` custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN#zzzSpecifier). One last thing, since your string have [UTC Offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), it would be better to parse it to [`DateTimeOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=net-6.0) instead of `System.DateTime`.

```
var dob = "Wed Jan 05 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0530";
var birth  = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(dob, 
                "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz",
                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                 DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Now we have `1/5/2022 12:00:00 AM +05:30` as a `birth` variable. You can even use it's [`.LocalDateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.localdatetime?view=net-6.0), [`.DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.datetime?view=net-6.0) or [`.UtcDateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.utcdatetime?view=net-6.0) properties which depends on which value you save in your database.

Other than that, a few things to consider;

- **Don't** put your connection string to your code as a plain text, read: [Where Should I Store a database Connection String?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4177060/447156)
- Also use [`using` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) to dispose your connection and command automatically since they are [`IDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=net-6.0).
- As a best practice, don't use `AddWithValue` method. [It *may* generate unexpected results](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use [.`Add()` method or it's overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#overloads).

Like;

```
using(var myConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
using(var sqlCmd = myConnection.CreateCommand())
{
     // Creater your command
     // Add your parameter and it's value
     // Open your connection
     // Execute your query
}
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for explanation. But one problem here it is that the default angular date format is like this only "Wed Jan 05 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)".I'm unable to change the format from angular. @Soner

Comment: @sai I didn't say to change the format. You have a variable called `dob`. Manipulate it to make it somehow successfully parse as I said.